# Thread counts and overall cpu utilization when running dask on a local machine

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am running dask with the following single/local machine settings:

```
ClusterWorkers=8
ThreadPerWorker=1
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=ClusterWorkers, threads_per_worker=ThreadPerWorker)
client = Client(cluster)
```

As can be seen in the screenshot the `dask` has detected 8 cores.  The physical machine is a  `macbook pro` with `core i7` and thus only *four* cores but a total of *8 hyperthreads*.  *python* is unable to distinguish between cores and hyperthreads.

[image]

Now when running a `dask.bag.compute()` operation the behavior is quite different than antcipated. Instead of seeing *eight* processes with *one* thread each - look what we have:

[image]

*10 to 12* threads *per python process*? *Why*?

Let's take a look at *cpu utilization*.  Here is the *cpu load* as reported by *Activity Monitor* - which has proven over years of use to be quite reliable: in particular when I run a *jvm* based threadpool or *standalone spark* it will reliably show very close to 100% utilization of all computing resources (approximately 800% cpu load ). Below we see more like 45-55%:

[image]

So the questions are:

- why so many threads instead of just one per process
- what might be preventing attainment of 100% of computing resources by the dask process pool.
- are there ways to structure the use of `dask.compute()` to achieve higher utilization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of threads in a python process is not the same as the number of worker threads, because there are some threads used for other, non-CPU-intensive, operations, such as communicating with other processes, diagnostics and serving the dashboard. Other processes, such as the one where your client lives, may have various things going on (a bare ipython session has 3 threads for me).

> what might be preventing attainment of 100% of computing resources

Many things! Referring to the [best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html), you should make sure that your partitions are large enough that computing on them takes much longer than the per-task overhead, but not so large that they saturate memory. You do a `.compute()` at the end, at which point all remaining data is passed to a single process (the client), which can be a major bottleneck if you haven't aggregated by a large factor. Often you want a method like `.to_textfiles` to write from the workers rather than accumulating into the client process.

> core i7 has only two cores but a total of 8 hyperthreads

Not four cores?? Note that the OS usually doesn't discriminate between logical cores, physical cores and discrete processor units. Python just takes the information from the OS.

Comment: I have seen references to `cores` being distinguished from `hyperthreads` associated with multiprocessing on python: i don't have the reference handy. i'm not sure how they could know - but just reporting what I had seen (in more than one place)